# When should I use code blocks or brackets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working through Eloquent Javascript and I wanted to learn some hard fast rules to using code blocks or bracket notation. Here's a sample block that I understand.. it's trying to just print out the number of chickens and cows that a farm has, and if the number is "7", it makes it 3 digits long so it reads "007".

```
function printFarmInventory(cows, chickens) {
    var cowString = cows
    while (cowString.length < 3) 
        cowString = "0" + cowString;
    console.log(cowString + "Cows")
    var chickensString = chickens
    while (chickensString.length < 3)
        chickensString = "0" + chickensString
    console.log(chickensString + "Chickens")
}

printFarmInventory(7,11)
=> 007 Cows
   011 Chickens
```

So it seems like we need code blocks when defining an executable code block for a function. Do we also need/use it for conditionals? Can the above code be written as:

```
function printFarmInventory(cows, chickens) {
        var cowString = cows
        while (cowString.length < 3) { 
            cowString = "0" + cowString;
        }
        console.log(cowString + "Cows")
        var chickensString = chickens
        while (chickensString.length < 3) {
            chickensString = "0" + chickensString
        }
        console.log(chickensString + "Chickens")
    }
```

Can we include brackets for while loops?

Apparently we DO use brackets for if/else conditionals... but what about while loops? Are these brackets optional?

```
function MyFunction(){
if(a==1){
alert("Hello world!")
}else{
alert("Goodbye world!")
}
}
```

PS: The reason why I am not simply testing this myself is because I do not have a good way to test Javascript code. What do people use? How do I write blocks of code in Chrome developer tools?

Comment: `"I do not have a good way to test Javascript code"` - You don't have... a web browser?  You can just write a web page with JavaScript in it and open that page in your browser.

Comment: @SLaks seems more complicated than a simple press on F12 still to just try something out for yourself...

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x12 http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.2 http://es5.github.io/#x12.5

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? Now I can't post anymore. Okay okay! I'll try to figure out how to conveniently do code blocks in developer tools!

Comment: Can you guys please not downvote! I am trying to improve and learn! Please! I even answered my own question!

Comment: if you're doing basically one thing in a function behind a conditional or loop, i don't see the big deal omitting them, and google's style guide says to omit them, but if it's in the middle of a block of code you should use them for clarity if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does indeed work:

```
function printFarmInventory(cows, chickens) {
        var cowString = String(cows);
        while (cowString.length < 3) { 
            cowString = "0" + cowString;
        }
        console.log(cowString + " Cows")
        var chickensString = String(chickens);
        while (chickensString.length < 3) {
            chickensString = "0" + chickensString
        }
        console.log(chickensString + " Chickens")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you use braces for blocks where they are optional is mostly a matter of style.  However, there are some pitfalls when you don't use them, and so I generally recommend that they always be used.

The classic example:

```
if (x)
   if (y)
     do_something();
else
   do_something_else();
```

The indentation here suggests that the developer's intent was for the `else` block to belong to the first conditional, while actually it belongs to the second.  If you use braces then this situation cannot happen.

Further, it's less likely that code gets damaged during maintenance:

```
if (foo)
   bar();

baz();
```

Suppose you are debugging and try this:

```
if (foo)
  debugger;
  bar();

baz();
```

Oops, the `bar()` is no longer part of the conditional block.  Again, always using braces avoids this problem, and prevents the rather awkward "add braces to add the `debugger;` line and remove them when done" dance.

Ultimately, there are no good arguments for omitting them when they are optional.  The worst possible thing that can happen is your coworkers might make fun of you (I have had this happen to me), which you should take as an opportunity to educate them!

Sometimes I run into the argument that if you don't use them you can write a block all on one line, like this:

```
if (foo) bar();
```

But this is a silly argument, because you can just as easily do this without sacrificing any readability:

```
if (foo) { bar(); }
```

Comment: Is debugger; another line of code? Sorry I have not yet used a debugger lines in my code. the point is that if you add the debugger line, the bar(); line gets pushed down and is no longer part of the conditional? Also, why do you include a baz(); line?

Comment: @Jwan622 `baz();` is code that is not part of the conditional, just as an example. `debugger;` is a statement that in most JavaScript environments does nothing at all (or causes a runtime error), but in certain ones (Chrome, for example) causes the JavaScript debugger to halt execution so you can inspect the program state at that point. And yes, my point is that if you don't use brackets, by adding that line you incorrectly remove `bar();` from the conditional block without intending to. If braces were there you wouldn't have.